# New to VBA, I want to define an array as a column in another file

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

How do I define an array as a column in a file whose file name is defined in a cell?
I have defined a name for these cells in the worksheet I am working on and I am also wondering how to use this in the VBA code.

Comment: Please make up your mind. Do you want to use VBA or not? Besides, opening a file whose name is in a cell cannot be done without VBA.

Comment: I need to define an array in VBA which I will use later in the code

Comment: What's not clear in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx)?

Comment: Are you just trying to define a range name pointing to another workbook?,Or are you trying to retrieve the values from the column in the other workbook?  Basically, it is logically impossible (AFAIK) to retrieve the contents of a file without "opening" the file, but if you are just trying to avoid the workbook being opened **in Excel** then you could use ADODB to perform an SQL query on the data.

Comment: I'm still not sure how to point the code to the file in the named cell and select a column on data in that file to store as an array

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the contents. If the other file needs to be opened to do so that is fine. Would anyone have a code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use something like this:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim columnArr As Variant

    For Each cell In Worksheets("MySheet").Range("WsNames").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants) '<-- loop through your named range not blank cells
        With Workbooks.Open(cell.Value).Worksheets(1) '<-- open workbook after current cell and reference its first worksheet
            columnArr = Application.Transpose(.Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Value) '<-- store referenced worksheet column "A" values down to last not empty cell
        End Witho
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False '<-- close opened workbook

        ' your code
    Next cell
End Sub
```

change "MySheet" and "WsNames" to your actual working worksheet and named range names